# How do I add a SQL Index in subquery?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

So I'm using Python with SQL, I want to add an index to my "lacris_afis_id_field_map" which are Key and Value pairs (json_fields). Problem is I don't know where to add the logic. It is within a select statement with subqueries and I only have used create index before I start a select statement. Since I cannot do that here. Where would I put this

```
CREATE INDEX ON interface.interface_configurations((json_fields->>'lacris_afis_id_field_map'));
```

into this

```
    def find_update_record(self, in_num):
        return self.db.queryOne("""
                  SELECT js.jail_staysid,
                   (SELECT JSON_AGG(DISTINCT(ni.identification))
                    FROM names_identification ni
                             JOIN names_identification_types nit ON
                        (ni.names_identification_typesid = nit.names_identification_typesid)
                    WHERE LOWER(nit.code) IN (SELECT nit.code
                        FROM names_identification_types nit
                        JOIN interface.interface_configurations ic ON nit.names_identification_typesid = (ic.json_fields ->> 'lacris_afis_id_field_map')::BIGINT
                    JOIN interface.interfaces i ON ic.interfacesid = i.interfacesid
                        WHERE i.tag = 'lacris'
                        AND ic.active
                        ORDER BY ic.created_at DESC
                        LIMIT 1;)
                      AND ni.active
                      AND CURRENT_NAMESID(ni.namesid) = cn.namesid) AS person_afis_ids,
                   (SELECT JSON_AGG(DISTINCT(ni.identification))
                    FROM names_identification ni
                             JOIN names_identification_types nit ON
                        (ni.names_identification_typesid = nit.names_identification_typesid)
                    WHERE nit.code = 'SS'
                      AND ni.active
                      AND CURRENT_NAMESID(ni.namesid) = cn.namesid) AS ss_nums,
                   (SELECT JSON_AGG(DISTINCT(ni.identification))
                    FROM names_identification ni
                             JOIN names_identification_types nit ON
                        (ni.names_identification_typesid = nit.names_identification_typesid)
                    WHERE nit.code = 'SID'
                      AND ni.active
                      AND CURRENT_NAMESID(ni.namesid) = cn.namesid) AS sid_nums,
                   (SELECT JSON_AGG(DISTINCT(ni.identification))
                    FROM names_identification ni
                             JOIN names_identification_types nit ON
                        (ni.names_identification_typesid = nit.names_identification_typesid)
                    WHERE nit.code = 'F'
                      AND ni.active
                      AND CURRENT_NAMESID(ni.namesid) = cn.namesid) AS f_nums,
                   (SELECT JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                           'num', ni.identification,
                           'state', ni.additional_field_1
                       ))
                    FROM names_identification ni
                             JOIN names_identification_types nit ON (ni.names_identification_typesid = nit.names_identification_typesid)
                    WHERE nit.code = 'OLN'
                      AND ni.active
                      AND ni.namesid = n.namesid) AS olns,
                   cc.code AS citizenship_code,
                   (SELECT JSON_AGG(DISTINCT(jie.external_id))
                    FROM jail_in_externalids jie
                    WHERE jie.jail_staysid = js.jail_staysid
                      AND jie.interface_external_name = (SELECT ic.json_fields->> 'external_id_name'
                                        FROM interface.interface_configurations ic
                                                 JOIN interface.interfaces i ON ic.interfacesid = i.interfacesid
                                        WHERE i.tag = 'lacris'
                                          AND ic.active
                                        ORDER BY ic.created_at DESC 
                                        LIMIT 1)::VARCHAR
                      AND jie.active) AS external_ids
            FROM jail_stays js
                     JOIN people p ON (js.peopleid = p.peopleid)
                     JOIN names n ON (p.peopleid = n.peopleid)
                     JOIN names cn ON (cn.namesid = n.currentid)
                     LEFT JOIN countries cc ON (p.citizenship_countriesid = cc.countriesid)
            WHERE js.in_num = :in_num
              AND js.active
              AND p.active
              AND n.active
            ORDER BY js.created_at DESC
            LIMIT 1;
            """)
```

queryOne function

```
def queryOne(sql, default=None, vars=None) -> Optional[DictRow]:
    _execute(sql, vars=vars, dn=1)

    if con().column_names is None or con().rowcount is None or con().rowcount < 1:
        return default
    return next(con())
```

If it isn't possible are there other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You should create the index at the same time you create your database tables, not in your select query.

Comment: I know that is usually standard, so it isn't possible then to add indexes on the fly with subqueries?